# Reading the config file in main ts angular

Tags: angular, bootstrapping

I have seen some similar questions but i couldnt figure out how to do this exactly. I have a config.json file and i want to read this file before the application starts. I have created a configuration service but i couldn`t figure out how to call it in main.ts(Diffrent structure than classes)

ConfigurationService class

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EmovieCat } from '../model/eMovieCategory';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { ConnectionHelper } from "app/config/connections";


@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {

    getConfiguration() {
        return this._http.get("app/config/config.json").map(res => res.json());
    }


    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }
}
```

Main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { ConfigurationService } from 'app/service/configurationService';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

/*I want to do something like below,7
 but i couldnt figure how to instantiate ConfigurationService

ConfigurationService cs = new ConfigurationService();
cs.getConfiguration().subscribe(resp=>{
  //set the server config here.
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
})
*/
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use Angular 2 environment variables. https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It`s a nice way, but i am expected to read from a config file so that i won`t have to rec2ompile if the server location changes. I will just change the config.json file. @KHAN

Comment: @Kay: this is exactly what we need to avoid. Client is asking us to use the same build for testing and live-deploy... using environment variables means that we'll need to make another build... I couldn't find the right answer until now, but I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the environment reference if you want and use Javascript fetch API to load JSON before main.ts

```
`fetch('assets/config.json').then(response => {
  return response.json()
})
.then(data => {
  if (data.production) {
    enableProdMode();
  }
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
})
` .
```

Then you can use APP_INITIALIZER in app.module.ts providers and call your service method to load config data before module loads.